# É possível utilizar o cordova com o nodemon?

Tags: node.js, apache-cordova

Estou começando a estudar mais o cordova porém toda vez eu preciso utilizar o

`cordova run browser`

para subir o servidor e testar o app, com node eu uso o **nodemon** para deixar o servidor atualizando sem precisar reiniciar, alguém sabe alguma alternativa pra deixar o cordova rodando pra sempre, do mesmo jeito que o **nodemon** funciona?

Cheguei a testar o nodemon da seguinte maneira:
`nodemon --exec cordova run browser`, porém sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução viável, o [Cordova Browser-Sync Plugin.](https://github.com/nparashuram/cordova-plugin-browsersync)

Com ele é possível editar o html do app sem precisar atualizar nada, ele faz um refresh no emulador que você esteja usando.